# InputStream for HTTP Header does not terminate

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to read the http header from the client using input stream but it does not seem to terminate. I wonder if there is any problem to read the request this way. I wanted this to work on both GET and POST request. Here is my code

```
private static byte[] readClientRequest(byte[] clientRequest, InputStream fromClient) throws IOException{
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream clientByteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while((bytesRead = fromClient.read()) != -1) {
        clientByteArray.write(bytesRead);
    }
    clientByteArray.flush();
    clientRequest = clientByteArray.toByteArray();
    return clientRequest;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add the caller code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general network socket does not known where the end is. It may be application protocol specific. For HTTP you can read one header line until end of line (bytesRead != '\n'). Then you should use `available` method to check that there is next part of data.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot! Instead of using available, I've used "\r\n\r\n" to check the end of the header. Then check the content-length to get the remaining unread bytes for POST.

Comment: be aware: content-length is optional in HTTP 1.1 
More limitation:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4